# Woocommerce how to show a custom text after removing item from cart with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a solution to show a custom text after ajax has finished removing cart items or after one has undone removing cart items in woocommerce.

Basically, I'm working on a project where I have to update 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' after an item is removed from the cart or after the 'undo' link has been cliked as shown in the image below.

Please see the image below

[image]

From the above image, the text that needs to be updated is the one that says "Order Delivery Type: Collection Only".

That text should be updated accordingly after an item has been removed from the cart or after the removal has been undone. The red banner should show different colours depending on the removed item.

All I'm looking for is a way to determine the ajax has finsed removing, or probably a way to use the same ajax woocommerxce is using and carry my custom text

Comment: If the answer below solves your issue please mark it as accepted (and possibly vote it up). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could mimic what the `update_cart_action()` does with a lower priority and add your own notices when an item is removed or restored.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', function() {
    if ( ! ( isset( $_REQUEST['remove_item'] ) || isset( $_REQUEST['undo_item'] ) ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $nonce_value = wc_get_var( $_REQUEST['woocommerce-cart-nonce'], wc_get_var( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'], '' ) );

    if ( ! empty( $_GET['remove_item'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $nonce_value, 'woocommerce-cart' ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Item removed.', 'woocommerce' ), 'success' );
    } elseif ( ! empty( $_GET['undo_item'] ) && isset( $_GET['_wpnonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $nonce_value, 'woocommerce-cart' ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Item restored.', 'woocommerce' ), 'notice' );
    }
}, 10 );
```